# How to install PHP 8 to 64-bit Arm architecture(aarch64)?

Tags: php, installation, arm64, php-8, oraclelinux

I use Oracle Linux with 64-bit Arm architecture in Oracle Cloud Ampere A1 Compute.

Since [official Oracle Linux](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-php.html) only support up to 7.4 and [Remi repo](https://forum.remirepo.net/viewtopic.php?id=4016) also doesn't support aarch64 , how to install PHP 8 to aarch64/arm64 especially oracle Linux or other RHEL base Linux?

I don't want to build from source, but if it's the only way to install please give me steps by steps. Because I tried to build from the source but failed with so many errors (I tried with some different configs).

I think Oracle Ampere A1 is similar to AWS Graviton2, but I don't see any reference also how to install PHP 8 to AWS EC2 Graviton2. Is PHP8 really not supported on arm64?

Comment: Not sure if https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-almalinux-oracle-linux/ helps.

Comment: @NigelRen it's use remi repo, so it's only work for x86/x86_64.

Comment: Build from source? Ask Oracle cloud support for help? Have you tried those approaches without success?

Comment: @O.Jones I tried from the source and there are a lot of errors, and I don't want to do also.  I prefer using existing repo like remi repo or ondrej, so it's easy if any update or add more module later.

Comment: And I don't think this question will support by oracle cloud support(free plan), as it's software problem. And my question is general about other Linux arm64 also, as I will try graviton2 and other arm64 server provider also.

Comment: Wait for 8.6 which have PHP 8.0  (of use CentOS Stream 8 which already have it)

Comment: See See https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/issues/214 aarch64 is now available for EL-9

Answer (score 0):

To list available Module Streams for PHP:

$ dnf module list php

To install PHP 7.4 :

$ sudo dnf install @php:8.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).